# PHP Imagick: problem converting ImageMagick command-line code

Tags: php, image-processing, xampp, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.8-66 Q16 x64 on Windows 8.1
My PHP is 7.4.1 on XAMPP.

I've been running the following command successfully with exec() in PHP:

```
convert _temp_.jpg 
( +clone -background black -shadow 88x3+2+2 ) 
+swap -background none -layers merge 
+repage -background #eeeeee -layers flatten 
+repage -shave 3x3 
( -size 100x100 xc:#eeeeee ) 
+swap -gravity northwest -geometry +5+5 -compose over -composite output.jpg
```

It takes an image, resizes it to fit in a 100x100 thumbnail, and adds a drop shadow to the image over a neutral #eeeeee background canvas. It works.

I want to rewrite it to use the Imagick PHP extension, but I'm having trouble translating it. Here's how I've translated it (with annotations), which is not working:

```
// convert _temp_.jpg 
$im = new imagick();
$im->readImage('_temp_.jpg');

// ( +clone -background black -shadow 88x3+2+2 ) 
$im_clone = clone $im;
$im_clone->setImageBackgroundColor('black');
$im_clone->shadowImage(88, 3, 2, 2);

// +swap -background none -layers merge 
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('none');
$im->addImage($im_clone);
$im->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_MERGE);

// +repage -background #eeeeee -layers flatten 
$im->cropImage(88, 88, +5, +5);
$im->setImagePage(88, 88, 0, 0);
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('#eeeeee');
$im->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);

// +repage -shave 3x3 
$im->cropImage(88, 88, +5, +5);
$im->setImagePage(88, 88, 0, 0);
$im->shaveImage(3, 3);

// ( -size 100x100 xc:#eeeeee )
$im_pseudo = new Imagick();
$im_pseudo->newPseudoImage(100, 100, 'xc:#eeeeee');

// +swap -gravity northwest -geometry +5+5 -compose over -composite output.jpg
$im->setImageGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_NORTHWEST);
$im->compositeImage($im_pseudo, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 5, 5);

$im->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

What am I missing?

Source image: [image: Starting Image]

Resulting image: [image: Ending Image]

Comment: What is not working? I would work through each step and get it working before I moved onto the next. One thing I would try changing is the ' ' to " "

Comment: I have done that. When I process just the parts corresponding to "convert _temp_.jpg 
( +clone -background black -shadow 88x3+2+2 ) 
+swap -background none -layers merge ", the result is not the same. Also, using single quotes vs. doubles quotes makes no difference.

Comment: You should attach your input image and expected output image along with the result you have.

Comment: Done. See above.

Comment: Maybe you could add how it's supposed to look.

Comment: I did. The desired result is the second image I uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

As I say if you go in steps you can see what is happening. This is from the php Imagick manual and creates the Shadow:

```
/* Read the image into the object */ 
$im = new Imagick( 'DOqeZ.jpg' ); 
$im->setImageFormat("png"); 

/* Make the image a little smaller, maintain aspect ratio */ 
$im->thumbnailImage( 200, null ); 

/* Clone the current object */ 
$shadow = $im->clone(); 

/* Set image background color to black 
        (this is the color of the shadow) */ 
$shadow->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) ); 

/* Create the shadow */ 
$shadow->shadowImage( 80, 3, 5, 5 ); 

/* Imagick::shadowImage only creates the shadow. 
        That is why the original image is composited over it */ 
$shadow->compositeImage( $im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 ); 

/* Display the image */ 
$shadow->writeImage('shadow.png');
```

[image]

UPDATE:
I thought I would let you see if you could do the rest

The creating the background and compositing it should work but extent should be better. I have other things to be getting on with but some updated code below for you to play with:

```
/* Read the image into the object */ 
$im = new Imagick( 'DOqeZ.jpg' ); 
$im->setImageFormat("png"); 

/* Make the image a little smaller, maintain aspect ratio */ 
$im->thumbnailImage( 80, null ); 

/* Clone the current object */ 
$shadow = $im->clone(); 

/* Set image background color to black 
        (this is the color of the shadow) */ 
$shadow->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) ); 

/* Create the shadow */ 
$shadow->shadowImage( 80, 3, 5, 5 ); 

/* Imagick::shadowImage only creates the shadow. 
        That is why the original image is composited over it */ 
$shadow->compositeImage( $im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 ); 

/* Create the background image 100x100 with a background colour */
/* Gravity seems to have no effect  */
/* $shadow->setImageGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);*/
$shadow->setImageBackgroundColor( '#eeeeee' );
$height = $shadow->getImageHeight();
$width =  $shadow->getImageWidth();
$shadow->extentImage( 100, 100, (((100 - $width)/2)*-1 ), (((100 - $height)/2)*-1 ));    

$shadow->writeImage('shadow.jpg');
```

[image]

**** Code updated to centre the image and use a hex value for the colour ****
[image]

Comment: I can't tell if you understand that the desired result is that the input image is resized to retain aspect ratio yet fit within (on top of) a 100x100 gray background. What you've created above is lovely, except that it's merely an image with a drop shadow. The goal of my routine (and the result it gets correctly in the command-line version) is an aspect-ratio-retained resizing of the original with a drop shadow that floats on top of a neutral gray background, hence all of the steps in my command-line procedure.

Comment: ...and by "floats above a neutral gray background" I do mean that the background is part of the composite picture. Save the second image I provided above and you'll see.